# The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded (the all duplicates reviewed)

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding

A WCF service connects to a remote server to get data (the server is not configurable by me).
I have increased maxReceivedMessageSize, maxBufferSize, maxBufferPoolSize, maxDepth, maxStringContentLength, maxArrayLength, maxBytesPerRead, maxNameTableCharCount in web.config and still the error persists.
I have tested many replies on the same question but none of them worked.
I have also increased maxItemsInObjectGraph with no success.
Any idea?

`

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMeteringDataService" allowCookies="true"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>`
```

Comment: Is that error message coming from the server? If so, you have simply sent a message that is bigger than they allow. What's in it? Have you tried sending the same message using PostMan or some known-good client?

Comment: A similar service (not a WCF) connects to the server and gets the data. so, it seems that there is no problem with the server side. Also, I have not tried PostMan, etc.

Comment: the point is that the message size quota is shown to be 65536. But I have increased the value in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to change the parameter on both the server-side and the client-side, or it will not take effect.